# How to allow other people who are in the same wifi or network to access localhost:3000 in React

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible in React to allow other people to access my website through `localhost:3000` like I access my website on development in local environment.

Every time, I make revisions, I wanna show that to other people in my office. I'm using React and Django. Can anyone let me know how to do that? a brief direction would be appreciated as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sufficient with that they'll know your ip for example:

> [PRIVATE_IP]:3000/

The difference between private and public IP are:

**Private IP:** address that identifies that device on the local network to which it’s connected.

**Public IP:** address that is provided by the Internet Service Provider ISP. This address identifies the specific LAN with a unique address on the Internet.

Hope to help you!

Comment: I googled my ip to get my ip address, but I can't access the localhost with the ip. After that, I got my ip through `ifconfig | grep 192.` on terminal and it worked. What is the difference? Must it start with 192?

Comment: So, the ip address starting with 192 is private one?

Comment: yeap! the range private ip are: 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255

Answer (score 0):

At first glance this isn't React specific because the problem is that your network configuration may not allow people to connect to a given port on your system. So instead you should be asking something closer to "how do I let other people connect to port 3000" on my machine?"

You'll need to provide your IP address, and ensure that they can connect to your machine. How they do that will depend on your OS and network configuration, but it could be as easy as visiting `http://YOUR.NETWORK.IP.ADDRESS:3000/` in their browser.